# Is there a zk-rollup proof explorer?

Tags: explorers, zksnark, layer-2, rollups

With the rise of various L2 solutions I started wondering whether it's possible to inspect the transaction *proofs* which are sent to L1. Is there a tool with an interface a'la block explorer, but oriented on L2 proofs?